# Enum, PList or some other storage?

Tags: ios, iphone, enums, storage

iOS 5.0 SDK

I have a method that took a parameter as a 'type' that I defined.  Lets call it 'Places'.  This type was defined as the following:

```
typedef enum {
    kBar = 0,
    kRestaurant = 1,
    kCafe = 2
} Places
```

My method would take a parameter of Places.

Based on the Place type passed in, I would append the type to the url:

ex: http://www.domain.com/place=1

However, the url parameter cannot be a number it has to be a string.

ex: http://www.domain.com/place=restaurant

I know enums cannot be strings so I am trying to figure out the right approach for this.  Do I have a plist and then read the plist into a dictionary?  Is there another way?

Comment: you've answered your question by yourself - the best option, will be to create a dictionary (in code or in plist) with supported strings and corresponding keys from your enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
typedef enum {
    PlaceTypeBar = 0,
    PlaceTypeRestaurant = 1,
    PlaceTypeCafe = 2
} PlaceType


@interface PlaceTypeHelper : NSObject
    + (NSString *) stringForPlace:(PlaceType)place;
@end

@implementation

+ (NSString *) stringForPlace:(PlaceType)place {
    NSArray *places = [NSArray arrayWithobjects:@"Bar", @"Restaurant", @"Cafe", nil];

   return [places objectForKey:(NSInteger)place];
}

@end
```

Headups, I've no tested the code yet.

Comment: I actually went this route instead of the function.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: I would go for `typedef NS_ENUM(..., ...) {...}` from now as we don't know whether the `PlaceType` does not intend to be used in any Swift code at all – otherwise the naming conventions look okay.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of different approaches you could take.  Here's what I might do myself.

Assuming there's a finite and known amount of values, you can do a simple function which returns the string for the given type :

```
(NSString*) StringForPlaceType(PlaceType thePlace) {
    switch(thePlace) {
    case kBar:
        return @"Bar";
    case kRestaurant:
        return @"Restaurant";
    case kCafe:
        return @"Cafe";
    default:
        // ...
    }
}
```

No need for an object or class unless you want for flexibility such as dynamic values and such.

Comment: That was actually where I was headed but did not know if there was another option.  Yes, there are a finite number of places.

Comment: There's a lot of possible solutions, they depend on the fact that values are known at compile time, if you expect them to change, etc... If values are know at compile time, and you don't expect them to change, I'd go with the function.  Good luck!